# Best Practices for Implementing Setters/Getters in Subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, getter-setter

If I have a superclass that must retain some functionality, thus requiring setters/getters (I realize this isn't ideal, but that's beside the point), when I implement a subclass, should I include a call to the superclass' setters/getters in the subclass even though I can technically invoke them without writing the code again?

I've posted an example of what I mean below.

```
class Parent {

   private int x;

   public void myMethod() {
      // Code here.
   }

   public void setX(int y) {
       x = y;
   }

   public int getX() {
       return x;
   }


}

class Child extends Parent {

   @Override 
   public void myMethod() {
      super.myMethod();
      // Different code here.
   }

   // Are the inclusions below really necessary? 
   public void setX(int y) {
       super.setX(y);
   }

   public int getX() {
       super.getX();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding methods to only call their super version is what you get by default without overriding!

In other words:

```
@Override
void foo() { super.foo(); }
```

results **absolutely** the same as behavior as ... not overriding that method at all.

So, to the contrary: you should consider making those getters and setters **final** to prevent subclasses from overriding them! And for the record: when overriding methods, you **always** want to put the @Override annotation on those methods (so the compiler can tell you when you only *think* you are overriding a method).

Comment: Thanks for the accept; I didn't expect that any more. I updated my answer with some more information; and side note: given the fact that your understanding of "inheritance" wasn't correct; maybe it would make sense for you to step back - maybe your thought "I need getter/setter" methods on the base class could be wrong too. Having getters isn't great, but allowing for setters is something that one should really try to avoid!

Comment: I was completing an exercise where the instructions stated I should use both getter and setter methods. Unfortunately, some of the instructional materials I've read are more concerned with teaching functionality as opposed to best practices, and that's what is confusing me. However, your answer was elucidating.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of inheritance is to NOT have to reimplement methods in a subclass if the superclass methods do what you need.  You should override only if the subclass method needs to do something different/more.

Answer (score 1):

> should I include a call to the superclass' setters/getters in the subclass

Firstly, if you want the child to have access to `private int x`, change private to protected.

The only reason I can think of when to return/set different data is when, for example, the subclass does some additional calculations upon `y` before setting `x`. Otherwise, if you just delegate to the super method, then that definition is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use superclass accessors if you need to access private fields from parent objects specifically. If you have different instance fields defined in the child class, you'd need separate getters to access those fields/variables.

Otherwise, just use the predefined super methods, which are inherited by all classes that extend the parent class.